# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1 from delete position from alertdialog box

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, android-recyclerview

I want to delete items with through alert dialog box. At the same time that I click yes, my app crashes, but the item is deleted at the same time, which is what I want, minus the crash.

[image]

[image]

Below I've pasted my RecycleAdapter.

Here's my code:

```
   public RecycleAdapter(ArrayList<RetrieveRunnerActivity> arrayList, Context context, Cursor cursor, OnItemClickListener deleteListener) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
    this.cursor = cursor;
    this.deleteListener = deleteListener;
}



private OnItemClickListener deleteListener;


public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onDeleteClick(int position);


}


public void setItemListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    deleteListener = listener;


}

public RecycleAdapter(ArrayList<RetrieveRunnerActivity> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;


}


@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewHolder RVH = new RecyclerViewHolder(view, deleteListener, context, arrayList);

    return RVH;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    RetrieveRunnerActivity retrieveRunnerActivity = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.Duration_column.setText(String.valueOf(retrieveRunnerActivity.getElapsed_time()));
    holder.Distance_column.setText(String.valueOf(retrieveRunnerActivity.getTotal_distance()));
    holder.date_heading.setText(String.valueOf(retrieveRunnerActivity.getDate()));
    holder.Entry_column.setText(String.valueOf(retrieveRunnerActivity.getId()));
    holder.deleteButton.getContext();

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView deleteButton;
    TextView Duration_column, Distance_column, date_heading, Entry_column;
    RunoraDatabaseHelper Runora_database;


    RecyclerViewHolder(final View view, final OnItemClickListener listener, final Context context, final ArrayList arrayList) {

        super(view);
        Duration_column = view.findViewById(R.id.Duration_column);
        Distance_column = view.findViewById(R.id.Distance_column);
        date_heading = view.findViewById(R.id.date_heading);
        Entry_column = view.findViewById(R.id.Entry_column);
        deleteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        deleteButton.setTag(deleteListener);
        final RecycleAdapter adapter = new RecycleAdapter(arrayList);
        Runora_database = new RunoraDatabaseHelper(context);



            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    dialogbuilder.setMessage("Delete activity permanently")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int
                                        position) {
                                    Runora_database.DeleteData(Entry_column.getText().toString());
                                    listener.onDeleteClick(position);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogbuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
```

Here is the error:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:405)
    at mobile.apps.DisplayHistory$5.deleteItems(DisplayHistory.java:189)
    at mobile.apps.DisplayHistory$5.onDeleteClick(DisplayHistory.java:182)
    at mobile.RecycleAdapter$RecyclerViewHolder$1$2.onClick(RecycleAdapter.java:122)
```

I've been stuck on this for a while. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: position in listener.onDeleteClick(position) refers to dialog listener which is different from adapterPosition

Comment: Thank you. I changed the position to getadapterposition. Much appreciated Hooman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer:

I changed this:

```
listener.onDeleteClick(position);
```

to this:

```
listener.onDeleteClick(getAdapterPosition());
```

Comment: The variable names in your dialog click listener are wrong, which is what caused this confusion. The standard name for the second param is `which`, and refers to which button on the dialog was clicked. You're clicking the "positive button", and `DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE` has a value of `-1`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener#onClick(android.content.DialogInterface,%20int)

Comment: Thanks Ben. I've made the necessary change.